# Could not resolve matching constructor exception with spring data elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have the following Entity definition for Spring data elasticsearch

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;

import java.util.List;


@Document(indexName = "ExcpetionStack", type="stack")
public class StateObject {
@Id
private String id;

@Field(type=FieldType.String)
private String exceptionName;

@Field(type=FieldType.String)
private String time;

@Field(type=FieldType.String)
private String exceptionMessage;

@Field(type= FieldType.Object)
private List<MethodStack> stackList;

public StateObject(){

}

public StateObject(String id, String exceptionName, String time, String exceptionMessage, List<MethodStack> stackList) {
    this.id = id;
    this.exceptionName = exceptionName;
    this.time = time;
    this.exceptionMessage = exceptionMessage;
    this.stackList = stackList;
}

public String getExceptionName() {
    return exceptionName;
}

public void setExceptionName(String exceptionName) {
    this.exceptionName = exceptionName;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getExceptionMessage() {
    return exceptionMessage;
}

public void setExceptionMessage(String exceptionMessage) {
    this.exceptionMessage = exceptionMessage;
}

public List<MethodStack> getStackList() {
    return stackList;
}

public void setStackList(List<MethodStack> stackList) {
    this.stackList = stackList;
}
}
```

and i have the following repository

```
import com.fico.ficoops.models.StateObject;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface StateObjectRepository extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<StateObject,String>{

//    Page<StateObject> findStateObjectById(String id, Pageable pageable);

}
```

when i run this application, i get the following exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stateObjectRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

where am i going wrong ? I have nested objects inside my document is it the cause of this, i tried removing that member variable from the model but that also didn't help...

Edit 1 : Adding the config file

```
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.custom.repositories")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.custom.services")
public class Config {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Config.class);

@Bean
public NodeBuilder nodeBuilder(){
    return new NodeBuilder();
}

@Bean
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws IOException {
    final Path tmpDir = Files.createTempDirectory(Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")), "elasticsearch_data");
    logger.debug(tmpDir.toAbsolutePath().toString());
    Settings.Builder elasticsearchSettings =
            Settings.settingsBuilder()
                    .put("http.enabled", "false")
                    .put("path.data", tmpDir)
                    .put("path.home", "/usr/share/elasticsearch");
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(nodeBuilder().local(true).settings(elasticsearchSettings).node().client());
}
}
```

Comment: You don't have a getter-setter for ID field.

Comment: added the getter and setter still not working, getting the same exception

Comment: Did you define @EnableElasticsearchRepositories with your config?

Comment: @rob yeah i have added that annotation to the config file

Comment: And it points to your repository, I trust?

Comment: yes it points to the repository package

Comment: The last thing I note is that you have a typo in your index name in the @Document annotation.

Comment: does that matter ?

Comment: Doesn't it need to match your es index?

Comment: it is matching the index name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137311/discussion-between-kumard-and-rob).

Comment: any solution to this ?